# ConditionalPannels not showing

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am having an weird issue when using conditional panels.

I have something similar to this

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(


selectInput(inputId = "graphT",
              label = "Type of Graph :",
              choices = c("x","y"),
              selected =  "x"),


conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.graphT == 'x'",
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot1")),

conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.graphT == 'y'",
      splitLayout(
      cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
        plotOutput(outputId = "plot1"),
        plotOutput(outputId = "plot2")
       ))

))
```

If I remove either of the condition panels, the other renders when I select the correct option. However if I keep both conditional panels nothing shows, I don't get any error or message, it's like I am not sending any input. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two outputs with the same id `plot1`. If you change in this chunk outputId to `plot3`

```
conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.graphT == 'x'",
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot1")),
```

and render the third plot on the server side it will work.

**Example:**

---

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(


  selectInput(inputId = "graphT",
              label = "Type of Graph :",
              choices = c("x","y"),
              selected =  "x"),


  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.graphT == 'x'",
    plotOutput(outputId = "plot3")),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.graphT == 'y'",
    splitLayout(
      cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot1"),
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot2")
    ))

))

server <- function(input, output) {
 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
   plot(1)
 }) 

 output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
   plot(1:10)
 }) 

 output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
   plot(1:100)
 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to do a sort of if/else. To represent either plot 1 or plot 1 and 2 but this works too